# AngularJS - filtering table with ng-repeat and filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have a table that has around 800 rows, each with two cells. The issue I'm running into is that it takes waaaaay to long to filter through. I was wondering if you had any suggestions for improving filtering time.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Type to search..." ng-model="search">
<tr ng-repeat="item in items|filter:search track by $index" ng-click="clickList($index)" class="tableRow">
    <td class="english" style="width: 50%">
        <p class="term">{{item.english}}</p>
    </td>
    <td class="spanish" style="width: 50%">
        <p class="term">{{item.spanish}}</p>        
    </td>
</tr>
```

EDIT:

My Items look like this:

```
var legalObject = [{
    english: 'accord and satisfaction',
    spanish: 'acuerdo transaccional'
        }, {
    english: 'acknowledged the same to be his free act and deed',
    spanish: 'reconoció el mismo como su escritura otorgada libremente'
        }, {
    english: 'adjudication',
    spanish: 'juicio en el tribunal de menores'
        }, {
    english: 'adverse witness',
    spanish: 'testigo desfavorable'
        }, {
    english: 'advice of rights',
    spanish: 'lectura de derechos'
        }];
```

Comment: can you post your items model?

Comment: what sort of data are you trying to filter through? without knowledge of the data, it's not really obvious why it would be slow;  it might be suggested to create a custom filter, but again, without knowledge of the data, it's not possible to design any logic for a custom filter...

Comment: Updated with a preview of my data.

Comment: Pagination is not really an option in the application. It has to be all in one view by nature.

Comment: ng-repeat by itself slows down dramatically based on the size of the objects it receives. If speed is critical, perhaps shape the data to perfection at the server. If your keys remain mostly unchanged, create an html partial without any loops i.e. a TR/TD for each portion of data you need to render. If you can chop up the data, perhaps using the newer angularjs router, you could use lazy loading as the person scrolls.

Comment: I'll make a suggestion, though I don't know if it will truly have an impact on performance.  it doesn't appear as though your data would have any repeat values, so the use of `track by $index` is unnecessary, and could be causing your performance issues.  also, I would consider simplifying `ng-click="clickList($index)"` to `ng-click="clickList(item)"`, instead of having to do an extra lookup in the controller.

Comment: It's a slight improvement, thanks. I have a couple of other ideas and all together, they just might give me what I want.